# Passing integer value from MDI parent to child and back

Tags: c#, static, mdichild, mdiparent

I have a Windows Forms app with an MDI parent form (`mdiBK`) and a few child forms (`form1` and `form2` are the ones that matter).

I would like to set an static int variable inside my parent form (`mdiBK`) and set it to '0'.

On 'form1' there are 2 buttons and both close `form1` and open `form2`
I want to set the static variable (in mdiBK) to `1` when `button1` is clicked and set it to `2` when `button2` is clicked.

In `form2` there is a button that closes `form2` and returns control to the parent form (`mdiBK`) and I want to set my variable *back to **zero***.

What code should I write to do that?

Comment: I have edited for clarity and readability. I now needs the OP to show his code...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: I think you need to look at the events in your forms, first on your mdiForm when you open the child form, set the variable...and so on...

Comment: I've improved your formatting to make the question more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way of exposing content in OOP is to use properties.
you can add a static property on your mdi parent form and use it anywhere in the code:

on the MDI form:

```
public static int MyInt {get;set;}
```

inside the button1 click event handler:

```
mdiBK.MyInt = 1;
```

inside the button2 click event handler:

```
mdiBK.MyInt = 2;
```

on the second form, inside the button click event handler:

```
mdiBK.MyInt = 0;
```